# Erlang: delayed initialization in gen_server

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

Say I have a gen_server callback module, `g`, a snippet of the code looks like this:

```
start_link(Args) ->
    gen_server:start_link(?MODULE, [Args], []).

process_packet(Ref, Packet) ->
    gen_server:call(Ref, MsgPacket={process_packet, Packet}).

init(Args) ->
    gen_server:cast(self(), MsgInit={init, Args}), %% delayed initialization
    {ok, state_not_initialized}.

handle_call({process_packet, Packet}, #g_state{}=S) ->
    {reply, Packet, S}.

handle_cast({init, Args}, _) ->
    State = #g_state{} = do_init(Args),
    {noreply, State}.
```

and another gen_server, `t`, whose job is to listen to a socket,
and if a specific packet is received, start a `g` to do something about the packet,
so, some code in `t` would looks like this:

```
handle_info({tcp, _Socket, Packet}, #t_state{}) ->
    case g:start_link(WhatEver) of
        {ok, Pid} ->
            g:process_packet(Pid, Packet);
        _ ->
            not_interested
    end.
```

Let `g`'s pid be `PidG` and `t`'s pid be `PidT`.

My question is, is it possible that `MsgPacket` (sent by `PidT` to `PidG`), arrives `PidG` before `MsgInit` (sent by `PidG` to itself)? if this happens, `PidG` whill crash, because `state_not_initialized` doesn't match with `#g_state{}` in `g`'s `handle_call`.

My guess is that this is entirely possible, but I failed to come up with a method to produce this scenario. Ideally, you could slow down the speed of the message transportation of the message `MsgInit`, but I doubt Erlang allows me to do this kind of thing. Any idea how to make `MsgPacket` arrives before `MsgInit`?

The fix is relatively easy, (assume my guess is right), you just `receive` some `ack` sent by `PidG`'s `do_init` in `PidT` right after `g` has been started, before doing the gen call.

**UPDATE**

Assume that my guess is right, to make the question more concrete, how to make one of the processes started by `kickoff_many/1` crash? (modified based on zxq9's example)

```
-module(spawn_spammer).
-export([kickoff_many/1]).

kickoff() ->
    {ok, Catcher} = spawn_catcher:start(),
    {echo, _} = spawn_catcher:process_packet(Catcher, {packet_from, self()}).

kickoff_many(N) ->
    lists:foreach(fun(_) -> spawn(fun kickoff/0) end, lists:seq(1, N)).


-module(spawn_catcher).
-behavior(gen_server).

-export([start/0,
         process_packet/2,
         init/1,
         handle_call/3, handle_cast/2, handle_info/2,
         terminate/2, code_change/3]).

start() ->
    gen_server:start(?MODULE, [], []).

process_packet(Ref, Packet) ->
    gen_server:call(Ref, {process_packet, Packet}).

init(_) ->
    gen_server:cast(self(), get_ready),
    {ok, not_ready}.

handle_cast(get_ready, not_ready) ->
    {noreply, ready}.

handle_call({process_packet, P}, _From, ready) ->
    {stop, normal, {echo, P}, ready};

handle_call({process_packet, _P}, _From, not_ready) ->
    {stop, normal, call_while_not_ready, not_ready}.

handle_info(_, ready) ->
    {stop, normal, unexpected, ready}.

terminate(_, _) -> ok.

code_change(_, State, _) -> {ok, State}.
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You can know the sequence of messages *relative to* process A and B, but you cannot know the message sequences relative to any other two processes *and* A and B (meaning, you can't know what order various streams of messages will be interleaved), and this also means you don't know the relative ordering of messages from A to B, and B to B.

How to avoid this? The most straight forward way would be to have your process T *spawn process G if I does not yet exist*. Or always spawn a G to handle the processing job. Or handle the processing itself. Or make the socket listener *not a gen_server*, but rather a pure Erlang OTP process (look up [proc_lib](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/proc_lib.html) -- I find this much smoother for socket listeners) and your weird conflicts between the gen_server world and the necessity of initializing certain aspects of socket handler processes can be made to go away.

To sum up:

- The ordering problem you think exists really does exist. In practice it will *almost never happen* -- until the most inopportune time in production, of course.
- Socket handlers should do nothing other than handling sockets.
- "Handling sockets" means translating between Erlang messages and network messages (if its TCP *they are not packets* it is a stream -- be careful), and dispatching to inner gen_* processes.
- Your initialization problem can be dealt with, but it is better to eliminate the need entirely. There is nearly always a way to do this -- when there isn't, there is `proc_lib`.

**UPDATE**

Here is what *can* happen if you don't *flush the mailbox* with a select receive searching for your magical first message.

Here we have a spamming process that will send a bajillion messages to the soon-to-be spawned gen_server:

```
-module(spawn_spammer).
-export([kickoff/0]).

kickoff() ->
    Spammer = start(),
    Catcher = spawn_catcher:start(),
    {Spammer, Catcher}.

start() ->
    ok = io:format("~tp ~tp: Starting up.~n", [self(), ?MODULE]),
    spawn(fun() -> loop() end).

loop() ->
    try
        spawn_catcher ! {self(), test_spam}
    catch
        _:_ -> io:format("~tp ~tp: Missed.~n", [self(), ?MODULE])
    end,
    receive
        cut_it_out ->
            ok;
        Unexpected ->
            io:format("~tp ~tp: Unexpected message ~tp~n", [self(), ?MODULE, Unexpected]),
            loop()
        after 0 ->
            loop()
    end.
```

Here we have that gen_server, trying to conduct a (supposedly) safe delayed initialization with itself:

```
-module(spawn_catcher).
-behavior(gen_server).
-export([start/0, init/1, handle_call/3, handle_cast/2, handle_info/2, terminate/2, code_change/3]).

start() ->
    ok = io:format("~tp ~tp: Starting up.~n", [self(), ?MODULE]),
    gen_server:start({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, [], []).

init(_) ->
    ok = io:format("~tp ~tp: Blank initialization.~n", [self(), ?MODULE]),
    gen_server:cast(self(), get_ready),
    {ok, not_ready}.

handle_call(Message, From, State) ->
    ok = io:format("~tp ~tp: Unexpected call: ~tp from ~tp~n", [self(), ?MODULE, Message, From]),
    {noreply, State}.

handle_cast(get_ready, not_ready) ->
    ok = io:format("~tp ~tp: Getting ready~n", [self(), ?MODULE]),
    {noreply, ready};
handle_cast(Message, State) ->
    ok = io:format("~tp ~tp: Unexpected call: ~tp~n", [self(), ?MODULE, Message]),
    {noreply, State}.

handle_info(Message, not_ready) ->
    ok = io:format("~tp ~tp: DANGEROUS MESSAGE: ~tp~n", [self(), ?MODULE, Message]),
    {noreply, not_ready};
handle_info({Spammer, test_spam}, ready) ->
    ok = io:format("~tp ~tp: Got first proper message. Sending reply.~n", [self(), ?MODULE]),
    Spammer ! cut_it_out,
    {stop, normal, ready};
handle_info(Message, ready) ->
    ok = io:format("~tp ~tp: Unexpected message: ~tp~n", [self(), ?MODULE, Message]),
    {noreply, ready}.

terminate(_, _) -> ok.

code_change(_, State, _) -> {ok, State}.
```

And here is how that plays out in the shell:

```
1> spawn_spammer:kickoff().
<0.33.0> spawn_spammer: Starting up.
<0.33.0> spawn_catcher: Starting up.
<0.99.0> spawn_spammer: Missed.
<0.99.0> spawn_spammer: Missed.
<0.100.0> spawn_catcher: Blank initialization.
<0.100.0> spawn_catcher: DANGEROUS MESSAGE: {<0.99.0>,test_spam}
<0.100.0> spawn_catcher: DANGEROUS MESSAGE: {<0.99.0>,test_spam}
<0.100.0> spawn_catcher: DANGEROUS MESSAGE: {<0.99.0>,test_spam}
{<0.99.0>,{ok,<0.100.0>}}
<0.100.0> spawn_catcher: DANGEROUS MESSAGE: {<0.99.0>,test_spam}
<0.100.0> spawn_catcher: DANGEROUS MESSAGE: {<0.99.0>,test_spam}
<0.100.0> spawn_catcher: DANGEROUS MESSAGE: {<0.99.0>,test_spam}
<0.100.0> spawn_catcher: DANGEROUS MESSAGE: {<0.99.0>,test_spam}
<0.100.0> spawn_catcher: DANGEROUS MESSAGE: {<0.99.0>,test_spam}
<0.100.0> spawn_catcher: DANGEROUS MESSAGE: {<0.99.0>,test_spam}
<0.100.0> spawn_catcher: DANGEROUS MESSAGE: {<0.99.0>,test_spam}
<0.100.0> spawn_catcher: DANGEROUS MESSAGE: {<0.99.0>,test_spam}
<0.100.0> spawn_catcher: DANGEROUS MESSAGE: {<0.99.0>,test_spam}
<0.100.0> spawn_catcher: DANGEROUS MESSAGE: {<0.99.0>,test_spam}
<0.100.0> spawn_catcher: DANGEROUS MESSAGE: {<0.99.0>,test_spam}
<0.100.0> spawn_catcher: DANGEROUS MESSAGE: {<0.99.0>,test_spam}
<0.100.0> spawn_catcher: DANGEROUS MESSAGE: {<0.99.0>,test_spam}
<0.100.0> spawn_catcher: DANGEROUS MESSAGE: {<0.99.0>,test_spam}
<0.100.0> spawn_catcher: DANGEROUS MESSAGE: {<0.99.0>,test_spam}
<0.100.0> spawn_catcher: DANGEROUS MESSAGE: {<0.99.0>,test_spam}
<0.100.0> spawn_catcher: DANGEROUS MESSAGE: {<0.99.0>,test_spam}
<0.100.0> spawn_catcher: DANGEROUS MESSAGE: {<0.99.0>,test_spam}
<0.100.0> spawn_catcher: DANGEROUS MESSAGE: {<0.99.0>,test_spam}
<0.100.0> spawn_catcher: DANGEROUS MESSAGE: {<0.99.0>,test_spam}
<0.100.0> spawn_catcher: DANGEROUS MESSAGE: {<0.99.0>,test_spam}
<0.100.0> spawn_catcher: DANGEROUS MESSAGE: {<0.99.0>,test_spam}
<0.100.0> spawn_catcher: DANGEROUS MESSAGE: {<0.99.0>,test_spam}
<0.100.0> spawn_catcher: DANGEROUS MESSAGE: {<0.99.0>,test_spam}
<0.100.0> spawn_catcher: DANGEROUS MESSAGE: {<0.99.0>,test_spam}
<0.100.0> spawn_catcher: DANGEROUS MESSAGE: {<0.99.0>,test_spam}
<0.100.0> spawn_catcher: DANGEROUS MESSAGE: {<0.99.0>,test_spam}
<0.100.0> spawn_catcher: DANGEROUS MESSAGE: {<0.99.0>,test_spam}
<0.100.0> spawn_catcher: Getting ready
<0.100.0> spawn_catcher: Got first proper message. Sending reply.
```

*THIS IS EXTREMELY UNLIKELY* but it *can* happen.

Comment: I believe this is incorrect. Check my answer for details.

Comment: The edited example contains call to erlang:register/2. This is not an example that author provided.

Comment: @PaulPeregud The provided example makes a call to gen_server:spawn/4, *hardly a weird thing to do when using delayed initialization*. The fact remains that this is something possible *using only gen_server defined startup calls*. It is entirely and in every way applicable. Furthermore I've seen this exact mistake in production MORE THAN ONCE. Also, Pids are *recycled* so you can get a stray reference to a Pid from long ago that is sending messages into space, and suddenly is sending somewhere that exists. I've *also seen that* in production. 99.999% of the time this is OK. But it *can* happen.

Comment: @zxq9 you used a trick (registered process name) in your example to let you send messages to the gen server asap, which leads to an ordering issue: if you use pid instead of name, you can communicate with PidG only after `gen_server:cast(self(), MsgInit={init, Args}), %% A` has been evaluated (the MsgInit doesn't have to be delivered though, and maybe it will be delivered after MsgPacket been delivered), while in your example, the `spawn_catcher ! blah` will be evaluated before A was executed.

Comment: ... I know this kind of inference is flawed, [10.8  Is the order of message reception guaranteed](http://www.erlang.org/faq/academic.html) doesn't cover the case P to P and Q to P, it would be good to preserve the order of the evaluation.

Comment: @NotanID Pids are also recycled. There is a finite pool of possible Pids on a single system. It is not *guaranteed* that the Pid that is spawned did not previously exist. I had to fix this *exact* bug that was *very* hard to reproduce in a production game chat server. Loggers were trying to talk to a db connection process that was spawned millions of times because of a resource error (partial hardware failure). A dead Pid was still being sent log messages while an unrelated process that got the recycled Pid tried to spin up with a message to self() as its init message. That was unregistered.

Comment: @NotanID The example above is *not* a contrived example -- its exactly what you are going to find yourself eventually doing when you've hardwired this antipattern into your way of doing things. You'll have a named process somewhere that crashes, and as it puts itself back together it will get flooded with messages before its message to self() arrives. There is a better way, and that's to *fully* init before entering the service loop and having a catch-and-log-unexpected clause in your generic receives. Amazing this idea is considered so radical.

Comment: @NotanID You asked *if it was possible*. It *is*. It is *highly unlikely* to actually be a problem, but my point is to answer your question -- and *it can*. Your data center could also get hit by falling space debris. If this happens and your process crashes, but its totally OK for it to crash, then whatever -- just let supervisors do their thing. But if state recovery after such a crash is expensive in some way, then starting the processes up in a way that this *can't* happen is the correct decision.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer. No, this is not possible.

This technique is sometimes called delayed initialization and is used quite often.

Long answer. No, this is not possible if you are using gen_server and not using selective receive.

From gen_server docs:

> The gen_server process calls Module:init/1 to initialize. To ensure a synchronized start-up procedure, start_link/3,4 does not return until Module:init/1 has returned.

Thing that you should consider here is following.

Who knows PidG at the moment when g:init/1 is running? Only PidG process itself. Process who started PidG will return from gen_server:start/x only after PidG will return from g:init/1.

Having established that, we know that {init, Args} is the first message in PidG's message queue. And since we are using gen_server, which (generally) processes messages one-by-one, you can be sure that PidG will also process message {init, Args} as first one.

There is no interaction between PidG and PidT at that point of time.

EDIT: Removing mention about returning {ok, State, 0} and receiving 'timeout', since it will fail because it creates race condition (see gen_server.erl). There is only one safe way: self() ! message under condition that you don't do such things as sending your pid anywhere in Module:init/x.

Comment: The *moment* a PID exists it is a valid target. It is *extremely* unlikely that a message will get in there before a message sent from self() will, but it may be possible to happen -- there is no guarantee that there is not a delay between the send and receive. I don't believe this has anything to do with when init() returns other than the PID will not be returned to whatever called the start function. The PID exists before that return (otherwise the call to `self()` wouldn't work), though, and if the process is registered, for example, that name could be resolved before init() is complete.

Comment: None of those scenarios is applicable to example provided by @"Not an ID" Question is about delayed initialization, and generally it is safe.

Comment: IMO its an ugly hack, is forced on the programmer in a tiny sliver of cases because of the way generic services are defined in OTP, and has a *much* more robust workaround in the form of proc_lib. The chances of it getting screwed up are *miniscule*, usually lower than the cases where `Pid = spawn(Foo), link(Pid)` instead of `spawn_link` can fail (and even that was mistaken for a safe case once upon a time), but to say that "it can't happen" is wrong. Check my answer update.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with synchronized initialization.